# Use APP_INITIALIZER to Abort Startup

Tags: angular

I have the following definition in my `app.module.ts` to force my application Properties service to initialize on startup (Properties Service is in the Core module):

```js
 * Initializer factory function to population the properties in $props on app startup
 * 
 * (This might not be acceptable in cases where the user is not logged in, revisit later)
 * 
 * @param $props 
 * @returns 
 */
export function initPropertiesService($props : PropertiesService) {
  return () => $props.init();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    // logging third-party
    HttpClientModule,
    // Third party
    // Custom Modules Go Here
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initPropertiesService,
    deps: [PropertiesService],
    multi: true
  }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the `init()` method:

```js
  // initialize service
  init() : void {

    // TODO: get rid of deprecation warning.
    this.$http.get<Property[]>(`${this.urlPrefix}/list`)
      .subscribe((response : Property[]) => {
        this.properties = new Map<string, Property> (
          response.map(prop => {
            return [prop.key, prop]
          })
        );

      },
      (error) => {
      },
      () => {
        this.initialized = true;
      });

  }
```

How can I force the application to abort the startup if init fails?

Answer (score 3):

I am giving you an alternative, I hope it fits your needs:

you can set a boolean `failed` in enviroments (must be true) and then bootsrap another component so you can show a nice error message

```js
init(): Observable<any> {
  return this.$http.get<Property[]>(`${this.urlPrefix}/list`).pipe(
    tap(response : Property[] => {
      this.properties = new Map<string, Property> (
        response.map(prop => {
          return [prop.key, prop]
        })
      );
      environment.failed = false; // default would be true
    })
  );
}
```

```js
  providers: [
    {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (propertiesService: PropertiesService) => () => propertiesService.init$().toPromise(),
    deps: [PropertiesService],
    multi: true
  }
  ],
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  async ngDoBootstrap(app) {
    if (environment.failed) {
      app.bootstrap(MyFailComponent);
    } else {
      app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, as long as it turns out that only the PropertiesService needs to be initialized on startup.

Comment: usually you create an `AppInitService`, you can pass any other service as a parameter of `init()` and do all the stuff you want